# autotools configure error when passing options using shell variable

Tags: bash, nginx, autotools, configure

I wish to call configure command (to compile nginx) from a bash script like this:

```
CONF_OPTS=' --with-cc-opt="-O2 -g"'
./configure ${CONF_OPTS}
```

but I got the following error:

```
./configure: error: invalid option "-g"
```

When I pass the options like:

```
./configure --with-cc-opt="-O2 -g"
```

I got no error.

To reproduce:

```
curl -O  http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz
tar xfz nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.14.2

OPTS='--with-cc-opt="-O2 -g"'
./configure ${OPTS}
```

Results

```
./configure: error: invalid option "-g""
```

But:

```
./configure --with-cc-opt="-O2 -g"
```

it is ok

I think it is not nginx related, but I look to me as bash quote substitution issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work like this:

```
$ CC_OPTS=--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g'
$ ./configure "$CC_OPTS"
```

so that the expansion of `$CC_OPTS` is passed as a single argument to `./configure`.

But if you wanted also to pass, maybe:

```
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-Map=mapfile'
```

through a variable, you would need:

```
$ CC_OPTS=--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g'
$ LD_OPTS=--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-Map=mapfile'
$ ./configure "$CC_OPTS" "$LD_OPTS"
```

because you need to pass *two* arguments to `./configure`, and:

```
./configure "$CC_OPTS $LD_OPTS"
```

passes only one, and will fail.